# getTitle() giving strange result on Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am running an automated test script in selenium-webdriver combined with Phantomjs environment.

I am trying to run my script by node.js (not using Python or C#)

Following are the steps of how I set up the environment:

1. #### Installing selenium webdriver:

   `C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS\>npm install selenium-webdriver`
2. #### Installing phantomJS

   Put the phantomjs scripts in the location:
   `C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS\node_modules\selenium-webdriver`:

   [image]
3. #### Running the standalone selenium server:

   [image]

Here is the test script [login-as-administrator.js] I am running below:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By = require('selenium-webdriver').By;
var until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;
var equals = require('selenium-webdriver').equals;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs())
    .build();
var baseUrl = 'http://saswatr3.ouh.co/login';
var expectedTitle = " Track Revenue ";

driver.get(baseUrl);
var actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
console.log(actualTitle);
if(expectedTitle === actualTitle)
{
    console.log("Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.");
}
else
{
    console.log("Verification Failed - An incorrect title is displayed on the web page.");
}
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys('saswat@matrixnmedia.com');
driver.findElement(By.id('password')).sendKeys('DarkPrince2012');
driver.findElement(By.id('_submit')).click();
driver.wait(until.titleIs('Track Revenue'), 1000);
driver.quit();
```

I run the above script through node.js

`C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS\node_modules\selenium-webdriver >node login-as-administrator.js`

When I am running this script, I am getting the following report as stated below:

[image]

As you can see, I am getting weird result when putting the `actualTitle` on log.

I can't figure it out, why such weird report in coming. Is there something I am missing out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getTitle` schedules a command that will be executed later (in your case, when the page is loaded) by the WebDriverJS framework. It returns a promise, not the title.

Try this:

```
driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {

    if(expectedTitle === title){
        console.log("Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Verification Failed - An incorrect title is displayed on the web page.");
    }
});
```

Instead of:

```
var actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
console.log(actualTitle);
if(expectedTitle === actualTitle)
{
    console.log("Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.");
}
else
{
    console.log("Verification Failed - An incorrect title is displayed on the web page.");
}
```

Also, remove the extra spaces for your expected title, like:

```
var expectedTitle = "Track Revenue";
```

Comment: Holy Jesus! you are genius. Thanks bro. @CViejo.. I will have some problem too, but this one I will accept. Can you help me in other issues too?